# Change style on button click react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm passing an array of objects from external js file to the main component to render:

```
const students = filteredStudents.map(i =>
  <div key={i.id} className='d-flex border-bottom'>
    <img src={i.pic} className='align-self-center border rounded-circle mx-4' />
    <div className='my-3'>
      <h2 className='fw-bold'>{i.firstName.toUpperCase()} {i.lastName.toUpperCase()}</h2>
      <div className='text-secondary ms-4'>
        <p className='mb-0'>Email: {i.email}</p>
        <p className='mb-0'>Company: {i.company}</p>
        <p className='mb-0'>Skill: {i.skill}</p>
        <p className='mb-0'>Average: {getAverageScore(i.grades)}%</p>
        <div className='mt-2 d-none'>
          {getGrades(i.grades)}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  // Here is a + button
  </div>
);
return students;
```

main component render:

```
const items = renderStudents(this.state.query, this.state.students);
return (
 <div id='students-card' className='overflow-auto border shadow-lg'>
   <input className='w-100' placeholder='Search by name' onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.query} />
   {items} // Array of objects being rendered here
</div>
);
```

Imagine there is a button instead of comment and when user clicks on it then `d-none` should be toggled on and off. I got completely stuck on this. Should I render every student object like a single component with it's state rather then my way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign an id and store it to a local state, use it as identifier for the current selected item and you can do your logic.

Check below example

```
const [selectedGrade, setGrade] = React.useState(null)
const [show, setShow] = React.useState(true)

const handleHideShowGrade = (id) => {
  setGrade(id)
  setShow(!show)
}

const students = filteredStudents.map((i, idx) =>
  <div key={i.id} className='d-flex border-bottom'>
    <img src={i.pic} className='align-self-center border rounded-circle mx-4' />
    <div className='my-3'>
      <h2 className='fw-bold'>{i.firstName.toUpperCase()} {i.lastName.toUpperCase()}</h2>
      <div className='text-secondary ms-4'>
        <p className='mb-0'>Email: {i.email}</p>
        <p className='mb-0'>Company: {i.company}</p>
        <p className='mb-0'>Skill: {i.skill}</p>
        <p className='mb-0'>Average: {getAverageScore(i.grades)}%</p>
        <div className={`mt-2 ${selectedGrade === idx && show ? '' : 'd-none'}`}>
          {getGrades(i.grades)}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  // Here is a + button
  <button onclick={() => handleHideShowGrade(idx)}
  </div>
);
return students;
```